# Can't get mic into 'yellow zone' in OBS or other programs

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, dialogue-recording

I own 3 mics.

- A Rode NT-USB USB mic
- A Movo 3.5mm shotgun
- A Rode 3.5mm lavmic

I've read (and agree) that when recording you want the sound level in the 'yellow' (-20 to -9dB) zone in OBS just below redlining.

This happens with all mics when they are, say, 10cm from my mouth, and the sound is great.

However, when it's further away - say when the shotgun is near the camera and off shot, or the lav is at the top of my shirt, the sound is in the middle of the green bar. This doesn't sound as good. I can raise the level in editing and it sounds fine, but ultimately I don't think it sounds as good.

Is this normal or should I be aiming for the yellow zone during all recording?

Should I buy an amp or 'fix' this some other way? Thanks.

**Update**

I'm running a line in to a PC Motherboard, ROG Strix X570-i

'Yellow' is -20 to -9dB in OBS

Comment: What values are "yellow"? Location recording will often use peak -18dBFS to make sure nothing ever has the chance to go into overs, nothing is too hot, none of the analogue stages are even raising a sweat. Just for fun, and some sound reasoning - https://www.massivemastering.com/blog/index_files/Proper_Audio_Recording_Levels.php

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit of a n00b. Yellow in OBS is -9 to -20. The lav and shotgun both hover around -40 to -25. Never gets close to -18. Link looks good thx.

Comment: I could increase gain in OBS, but I guess that will lower quality a bit / amplify noise? As am aim getting around -18 without boosting gain is better right?